# Crash in HttpHandler because of stream size

Tags: c#, iis, httphandler, basichttpbinding

I have written a HttpHandler in order to receive (upload) some files.
It's running on IIS 8.
My code works, but only for very small files (< 1-2 MB).
For larger files the code just crashes - not even throwing an exception - it just stops and sends back a "500 internal server error" message to the client.

My code looks like this:

```
        int bufferSize = 4096;
        string parameterString;

        using (var bs = context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true))
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] fileContents = new byte[bufferSize];
            int charsRead = bs.Read(fileContents, 0, bufferSize);

            while (charsRead > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(fileContents, 0, bufferSize);
                charsRead = bs.Read(fileContents, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            parameterString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
```

When I get my debugger attached it just stops at the last line.

My config looks like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="XXXX" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="21474836470">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

I'm lost at this point as I do not understand why my last line should be a problem?
Is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do... eventually there will be a file which is too big to be uploaded as once...

so you need to rethink your approach, best solution is to upload the file in chunks / parts. take a look on this [sample](http://forums.asp.net/t/1742612.aspx?How%20to%20upload%20a%20big%20file%20in%20Mvc%20)

this need to be handled client / server side

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint to chunk up the file. I will invest in this sooner or  later - in my current case later.

I ended up with this code and at least it helped for my current requirement:

```
parameterString = new StreamReader(context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true)).ReadToEnd();
```

I don't know why exactly this works while my former approach did not but hey... it works so far...